# Separate page.tpl file for URL

Tags: theming, 7

I have created a custom module with page URL like `$items['testpage/get']`. How can I create a separate page.tpl file for this URL? Link is like: `http://199.x.x.x/mysitename/testpage/get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's based upon the path.  In D6:

`page-testpage-get.tpl.php`

In D7:

`page--testpage-get.tpl.php`

(Although D7 might want `page--testpage--get.tpl.php` due to its love of double dashes :)

All about templates and their suggestions can be found here:

D6: http://drupal.org/node/1089642

D7:  http://drupal.org/node/1089656

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Jimajamma, I wil try and give update of this stuff..